# Substring elements of an array with an array of strpos values

Tags: php

I have an array which contains dynamic number of keys & elements. I also have an array which contains strpos values yet it has same keys with other array.

What i want to do is using the function substr to all elements of first array in which the **needleS** will be the elements of second array. Here is example arrays which are similar to mine. (please care key numbers of these elements are allways dynamic, i need a dynamic function, not static.)

```
Array
(
[213] => Dark Kiwi
[451] => Dark Apple
[789] => For Real Dark Apple
)
```

Now as i want to remove everything before the word "Dark", i have strpos of the word "Dark" in these elements.

```
Array
(
[213] => 0
[451] => 0
[789] => 12
)
```

Please note that keys are same in both of the arrays. What i need is exactly something like this:

```
aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray,$secondArray)
```

**All help is appreciated, thanks for your time. PHP version: 5.6**

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem. Why are you dealing with the array of offsets anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `12` substring should be 9.

Otherwise, you're probably looking for array_map:

```
<?php

$firstArray = [
213 => 'Dark Kiwi',
451 => 'Dark Apple',
789 => 'For Real Dark Apple'
];

$secondArray = [
213 => 0,
451 => 0,
789 => 9
];

function aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray,$secondArray)
{
    // Note this loses your keys because array_map is being used with two parameters
    return array_map(function($first,$second)
    {
        return substr($first,$second);
    },$firstArray,$secondArray);
}

echo '<pre>',print_r(aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray,$secondArray),true),'</pre>';
```

If you need to keep the 12, and you need to keep your keys, you could use this approach:

```
<?php

$firstArray = [
213 => 'Dark Kiwi',
451 => 'Dark Apple',
789 => 'For Real Dark Apple'
];

$secondArray = [
213 => 0,
451 => 0,
789 => 12
];

function aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray,$secondArray)
{
    foreach($firstArray as $k=>$v)
    {
        $firstArray[$k]=substr($v,$secondArray[$k] == 0 ? 0 : $secondArray[$k]-3);
    }
    return $firstArray;
}

echo '<pre>',print_r(aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray,$secondArray),true),'</pre>';
```

Or do it in one step:

```
<?php

$ar = [
213 => 'Dark Kiwi',
451 => 'Dark Apple',
789 => 'For Real Dark Apple'
];

echo '<pre>',print_r(array_map(function($el)
{
    return substr($el,strpos($el,'Dark'));
},$ar),true),'</pre>';
```

A regexp might also make more sense than substr and strpos depending on what you're trying to do:

```
<?php

$ar = [
213 => 'Dark Kiwi',
451 => 'Dark Apple',
789 => 'For Real Dark Apple'
];

echo '<pre>',print_r(array_map(function($el)
{
    return preg_replace('/^.*?(Dark.*$)/','$1',$el);
},$ar),true),'</pre>';
```

All code above tested on phptester.net

Comment: Thanks a lot. What should i change on the first function you have given if i want to delete a part of the string starting from the end of the string? In this case, $firstArray[789] would be "For Real".

Comment: If you need to keep your `12`, you could use `return substr($first,$second == 0 ? 0 : $second-3);` Keep in mind array_map, when used with two parameters, loses its array indexing and flattens the array losing your original keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to return what you need like the following

```
$a1 = array(213 => 'Dark Kiwi', 451 => 'Dark Apple', 789 => 'For Real Dark Apple');
$a2 = array(213 => 0, 451 => 0, 789 => 12);

function aFunctionToSubstrArray($a1, $a2) {
    return array_map(function($val) use ($a1, $a2) {
    $key = array_search($val, $a1);
    return substr($val, $a2[$key]);
}, $a1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing that function is simple with standard PHP constructs. I just leave you with the code. Just ask if anything looks unfamiliar.

```
aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray, $secondArray) {
  $return = array();
  foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = isset($secondArray[$key] ? substr($value,$secondArray[$key]) : $value;
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `foreach()` function:

```
aFunctionToSubstrArray(&$a,$p) {
 foreach($a as $i => $el) {
  $a[$i] = substr($el, $p[$i]);
 }
}
```

Then you just apply:

```
aFunctionToSubstrArray($firstArray,$secondArray)
```

Comment: Thank you I havn't noticed that small ampersand :)